# Why do I sometimes get a Null reference exception after a ?. check?

Tags: c#

I have an app running 24/7 on my desktop at home which uses a websocket library to connect to its services (this part is not written by me but I have the code), and very rarely it throws a `NullReferenceException` on this line:

```
socket?.Dispose();
```

It's set up so that it reconnects about every 3-5 minutes due to the service's unreliability. So let's say per day this line may be executed ~300 times. This has happened probably every 3-4 months for the last 3 years. The app has been updated to the latest version of c# framework regularly, since 4.5.

In what circumstances can this exception be occurring?

Comment: Maybe a race condition

Comment: What is the content of the `Dispose` method?

Comment: Is the socket or Dispose method a custom implementation?

Comment: [source of the `socket.Dispose()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebSockets/WebSocket.cs,3240ede4548fc3fd,references) :p

Comment: That's abstract so there must be an overriding method

Comment: My guess is that `socket` is not giving the nullreferenceexception but the implementation of the `.Dispose()`. @ngeksyo looks like websocket is abstract so it must indeed be a a custom implementation

Comment: There isn't, it's just a regular unmodified implementation. I'm not sure about race condition but I think it might have something to do with how long it's running. Perhaps it's improperly closing the sockets and after a while it runs out of its allowed limit and that somehow results in the exception I'm getting.

Comment: What type is `socket` variable? the source you linked is an abstract class. is a custom implementation based on `WebSocket`? `ClientWebSocket`? `WebSocketbase`?

Comment: Pretty iffy code.  If you can't know whether the socket reference is valid, how could you know it is safe to dispose?  Surely this was a band-aid for an existing race bug.  Yup, doesn't work.

Comment: So, what's stack trace of this exception?

Comment: Can you show us how `socket` is getting created?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) states that for `obj?.DoSomething()`, emphasis mine:

> The new way [using ?.] is *thread-safe because the compiler generates code to evaluate [obj] one time only*, keeping the result in a temporary variable.

So the problem can only be caused by the execution of `Dispose()`, whether part of the framework or your own implementation.